# Doctrine event listener "..." must specify the "event" attribute

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, event-listener

I want to register Doctrine Event Listener to hash user's password before persisting `User` object to database:

This is my Event Listener class:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Doctrine;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class HashPasswordListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return ['prePersist', 'preUpdate'];
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if (!$entity instanceof User) {
            return;
        }

        $this->encodePassword($entity);
    }

    /**
     * @param User $entity
     */
    private function encodePassword(User $entity)
    {
        $encoded = $this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword($entity, $entity->getPlainPassword());
        $entity->setPassword($encoded);
    }

    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if (!$entity instanceof User) {
            return;
        }

        $this->encodePassword($entity);
    }
}
```

And I register this event listener in `services.yml` file

```
    AppBundle\Doctrine\HashPasswordListener:
    tags: ['doctrine.event_listener']
```

But whenever I want to insert a user either by loading fixtures data or from the web application I receive such an error:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
  Doctrine event listener "AppBundle\Doctrine\HashPasswordListener" must specify the "event" attribute.
```

I tried to add event attribute in `tags` that didn't work either.

I'm using Symfony version 3.3 with Doctrine 2.5

Configured Doctrine in `config.yml` so:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver: pdo_sqlite
    path: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/sqlite.db'
    charset: UTF8
```

Where is the fault?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html#configuring-the-listener-subscriber Note the difference between event listener and event subscriber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use un subscriber so you must tag doctrine event subscriber not event listener that requires attribute event.

AppBundle\Doctrine\HashPasswordListener:
     tags: ['doctrine.event_subscriber']

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. I should have configured the event listener in `service.yml` so:

```
AppBundle\Doctrine\HashPasswordListener:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
```

This worked perfectly.

Comment: You are now using your class a listener. If you are using it as a listener, you shouldn't implement the EventSubscriber and you should remove the `getSubscribedEvents` as they are now useless. If you want the class to be a subscriber you should just use the `doctrine.event_subscriber` tag like @TAbdelmalek said.

Comment: Yeah I have been fooled by _autocomplete_. In fact the class should have been `Event Subscriber`, not `Event Listener`, so renamed `HashPasswordListener` to `HashPasswordSubsciber` and configured this in `services.yml` so: ```AppBundle\Doctrine\HashPasswordSubscriber:
        tags: ['doctrine.event_subscriber']```
Worked like a charm.

Comment: To be honest, the name of you class means nothing. If your class is a listener it requires the `doctrine.event_listener` tag with the `event` property. If it is a subscriber (meaning it sets its own listeners via the `getSubscribedEvents` method) then you need the `doctrine.event_subscriber` tag and `getSubscribedEvents` method. The `Listener` or `Subscriber` suffixes are just a naming strategy to enable you/other devs to easily identify class uses.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add an EventListener inside the Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=XXXX::class)
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks() NEED IT !
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"App\EventListener\XXXXListener"})
*/
class XXX
```

Then in you EventListener :

```
class XXXListener
{
    public function preUpdate(XXX $xxx, PreUpdateEventArgs $event): void
    {
        $xxx->setDateUpdate(new DateTime());
    }
}
```

Doc : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure the event attribute in your services.yml file for that event listener. It won't work w/o, which is why you see the error message.

For a full example please see

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html